# Creating a XOR key in Python

Tags: python, encryption, xor

This has to do with encryption/decryption. I have an original string that i've created list of characters from.

```
['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', ' ']
```

I've encrypted the original string into a second list.

```
['h', '=', 'g', 'l', 'x', 'k']
```

What I need to do is create a XOR key so that `encrypted list ^ XOR key = original list`

How to create a XOR key (list) in order to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Note that by xor-ing you can obtain ASCII control characters.

Comment: Do **NOT** use `encryption` and `xor` in one sentence.

Comment: Apart from the recommendation not to consider XOR an encryption, the values you are looking for are those you get by xoring each element from first list with the corresponding element from second list. Only by chance (or if created that way) that value will be identical for all indexes. If they are diffferent and the key sequence is completely known to receiver without being spyable, then you have a one-time-pad encryption. Yes encryption, unbreakable even. But only if you use a different key sequence for each message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be way off here...

```
>>> original = ['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', ' ']
>>> xored = ['h', '=', 'g', 'l', 'x', 'k']
>>> key = [chr(ord(a) ^ ord(xored[i])) for i, a in enumerate(original)]
>>> key
['\x0e', 'T', '\x15', '\x1f', '\x0c', 'K']
>>> [chr(ord(a) ^ ord(xored[i])) for i, a in enumerate(key)]
['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', ' ']
>>> [chr(ord(a) ^ ord(key[i])) for i, a in enumerate(original)]
['h', '=', 'g', 'l', 'x', 'k']
```

XOR'ing the ordinal of each element in original with the corresponding indexed ordinal of the key gives you the xored version.

**EDIT**
Since you seem to be trying to xor the list itself you can do this

```
class XOR(list):

    def __xor__(self, other):
        return map(chr, [ord(x[0]) ^ ord(x[1]) for x in zip(self, other)])


l = XOR(['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', ' '])
print(l ^ ['\x0e', 'T', '\x15', '\x1f', '\x0c', 'K'])
```

Comment: thank you sir; that got me closer. Right now, i'm getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^:  'list' and 'list'` when I try to XOR the 'xored' against the 'key'